# applicate a function only on one element of table loop in TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using an Angular TypeScript 12

I have a table which contains list of products and I need to make a choice of adding a discount to each one of products.
I tried something but it gets applicated to all the elements of the loop, but I want it to be applicated to the only product I enter a discount for.
and when I make the discount input outside it doesn't repeat for each product.

here is what I tried in HTML:

```
   <table>
       <thead>
           <tr>
               <th>product</th>
               <th>price</th>
               <th>discount</th>
           </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
           <tr *ngFor="let prod of products">
               <td>{{prod.name}}</td>
               <td>{{prod.price}}Dhs</td>
               <td><input type="number" (keyup.enter)="calculateDiscount(prod.price)" [(ngModel)]="discount" placeholder="0" </td>
           </tr>
       </tbody>
   </table>
```

and here is the function I used:

```
calculateDiscount(price?:number)
  {
    this.pricepr=price;
    if(this.pricepr!==undefined)
    {

      this.discounttotal=((this.pricepr*(this.discount))/100);
      console.log(this.discounttotal)

      this.totalwithDiscount=this.total-this.discounttotal;
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

## Solution 1

Create an array of discounts in this component and apply each product's discount to the correct index:

```js
export class ListProductComponent {
  discounts = [];
  applyDiscount(i: number, discount: number) { 
    // Apply only for product
    this.discount[i] = discount;
  }

  calculateDiscount() {
    // Calculate all your discounts based on this.discounts
  }
```

with the following html

```html
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let prod of products; index as i">
    <td>{{prod.name}}</td>
    <td>{{prod.price}}Dhs</td>
    <td>
      <input
        type="number"
        (keyup.enter)="applyDiscount(i, prod.price)"
        [(ngModel)]="discount"
        placeholder="0">
    </td>    
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

[Codesandbox for solution 1](https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-bush-cqir4)

## Solution 2

Make your product its own component (and have its own context) and emit something like `priceWithDiscount` from this component to pick up in your table component and calculate the total discount.

Comment: this is what i tried but it didn't work :

Comment: `   apply_discount(i:number,price?:number)
{
  this.pricepr=price;
  this.discounts[i]=this.enteredremise;

  if(this.pricepr!==undefined)
  {
    this.discounttotal=((this.pricepr*(this.discounts[i]))/100);
    console.log(this.discounttotal)

    this.totalwithDiscount=this.total-this.discounttotal;


   }  

}  `

Comment: btw i don't have the discount field in my class of products @Askirkela

Comment: @amilana please check the codesandbox link I added in my answer

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of logical errors in your model:

1. You have a "number" type field with `keyup.enter` action, which doesn't make sense. Generally people do not press "enter" when entering a number. In fact you can change the html field with a mouse click, so your function will not get executed. You probably want to use `(change)` or `(input)` instead.
2. You appear to have an input field that allows you to enter a value, and then after entering it, you want that same field to change value based on the function. That doesn't seem right to me. Probably split that into 2 fields. Or better yet, one input field and then just a display field for the result (not input).
3. Your function seems to update a whole bunch of global variables, which may or may not be needed. You might want to simply what you are trying to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your binding is not correct

```
[(ngModel)]="discount"
```

The discount property on your component is just one and applied for all the product iteration, the best way to do this in my opinion, is to keep a nullable discount property on the product object and bind it there, and set it with your discount calculation

```
[(ngModel)]="prod.discount"
```